# display pricing information outside Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, integration

We have a Salesforce integration within our application where users can access their Salesforce account using SAML SSO & JIT user provisioning. We also display few account & user details. We want to display Salesforce pricing information (the amount to be paid to Salesforce.com for subscription, due date etc). from where and how to fetch this data for any particular account?

Comment: Nothing helpful in that regard. We display Account / User / contact info using SOAP API from Salesforce Object. But I cannot see any object where billing information is stored.

Answer (score 0):

The contract with Salesforce.com is not stored in your instance of Salesforce.com.  It is stored in Salesforce's version (the company uses its own software for sales).

Every contract with Salesforce is different, but almost all of them depend on the number of users of a certain type.  You can build a report that shows count of active users per license type.  Combine that with information from your actual contract (the one that you signed with Salesforce.com), and you should have a good estimate.